# How to adding array data to existing array data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, php-7

how to adding array data to existing array?

For example I already have array from cookie:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [name] => People 1
    [address] => Indonesia
)
```

I want to add another array to existing array I have, for example the array:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 2
    [name] => People 2
    [address] => USA
)
```

And I want an output array like this:

```
Array ( 
array(
    [id] => 1 
    [name] => People 1
    [address] => Indonesia
),
array( 
    [id] => 2
    [name] => People 2
    [address] => USA
)
)
```

I want to create like a shopping chart that save data temporary

Comment: What have you tried? There are many ways to achieve this. Have look around.

Comment: @Hisham Yes sir, I have tried with array_push, array_combine, $array1 + $array2

Comment: And what is the output? Any of those methods can provide you the desired result. Can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can create a new array and push your other arrays into it.

```
$arr = [];

$arr[] = $arr1;
$arr[] = $arr2;

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I have found solution with 

$data= $this->session->tempdata('peopledata');
$newarray = array('id'=> '2', 'name' => 'People 2', 'address' => 'USA');

$data[] = $newarray;
$this->session->set_tempdata('peopledata', $data, 300);

But it's a same concept, thanks for your help